# How to fill the area under the curve in Matlab

Tags: matlab

The user gives a function, and I make the graphic in an axis with `syms(x)` and `ezplot(funcion)`. And in another case, the user gives the function and the interval for `x`. In the second example, I use `plot()` instead of `ezplot()`. Here are my codes=

```
syms x;

funcion=eval(get(handles.txtFuncion, 'String'));

ezplot(funcion);
```

The second code is this:

```
a=eval(get(handles.txtA, 'String'));

b=eval(get(handles.txtB, 'String'));

x=a:b;

funcion=eval(get(handles.txtFuncion, 'String'));

plot(x,funcion);
```

Comment: How about [`area`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/area.html)? As an aside, depending on the format of your function strings I would recommend using [`str2func`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2func.html) and/or [`feval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/feval.html) rather than `eval`.

Comment: How exactly can i use the area function, i cant see how to use it properly

Comment: What are some example strings for `a`, `b`, and `funcion`?

Comment: `funcion=x^2` and `a=-10` `b=10`

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the symbolic math toolbox so I can only address the second code.

Given the sample data provided:

```
a = -10;
b = 10;
x = a:b;
h.areaplot = area(x, eval('x.^2'));
```

Produces:

[image: area plot]

Edit: Alternatively you can modify your function input syntax to work without needing `eval`:

```
a = str2double(get(handles.txtA, 'String'));
b = str2double(get(handles.txtB, 'String'));

x = a:b;

funcion = str2func(get(handles.txtFuncion, 'String'));

h.areaplot = area(x, funcion(x));
```

Where your text inputs now take the form `'@(x) x.^2'`

Comment: Yes, you need the area function.